# How do I install kernel v3.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

Now that [v3.6 of the kernel has been released](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/9/30/152), is it available in any trusted PPAs? If not, I don't mind compiling it on my machine itself (I have never done it before though). I'd love it if I had step-by-step instructions.

Comment: This must be duplicate of How to install Kernel. [See at my blog post](http://penreturns.rc.my/2012/10/how-to-install-linux-kernel-v36-quantal.html)

Comment: Thanks! Should I be concerned that it has `quantal` in the name? I am on 12.04 (Precise).

Comment: Btw im using it now, if it not works very well, make sure you know how to remove and select old kernel when boot.

Answer (score 1):

Download kernel files from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/. Like for kernel v3.7.1-raring download your required files. For **x86_64** download the "**amd64**" files, for **x86** download the "**i386**" files, for **ARM** download the "**armhf**" files. And for all architectures download the "**all**" file. Then put them in a folder, like in Downloads/kernel. Then from terminal go to that folder, like "cd ~/Downloads/kernel". Then run "**sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb**", enter password when prompted. When installation completes, restart. That's all. You can check your kernel version by entering "**uname -a**".
Thanks.